# CM7 default dialer - how do I set international prefix?

Tags: cyanogenmod, phone-app

I installed vanilla CM7 (7.2.0), and ther is one thing that drives me crazy that I don't know how to fix. [According to this](http://androidforums.com/triumph-all-things-root/518751-cm7-cant-dial-1xxxxxxxxxx-numbers.html), the default dialer that comes with CM7 has "011" international prefix configured. This makes it drop all the calls to the phone numbers starting with "+".

Here's what somebody wrote about solution:

> This has been driving me crazy for ever. Finally played around with it
>   today and if you go into settings then call settings tap on
>   International Prefix remove the 011 and save. Do not put the +1 there
>   leave it blank and it will call the +1 numbers tried it on 3 of my
>   numbers after I did it and it worked on all. Hope this helps.

I am not sure what version of CM7 is the guy using, but on mine this option is nowhere to be found. Is there another way to configure this prefix, such as going directly to some sqlite database or something of that kind?

UPDATE: I dumped files from /data/data/com.android.phone/shared_prefs, and none of them seems to define any dialing rules:

```
# cat _has_set_default_values.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<boolean name="_has_set_default_values" value="true" />
</map>
# cat com.android.phone_preferences.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<boolean name="rotate_incall_screen" value="false" />
<boolean name="button_hide_hold_button" value="false" />
<boolean name="button_force_touch" value="false" />
<string name="preferred_umts_network_mode_key">4</string>
<string name="vm_number_key_cdma">*********</string>
<boolean name="button_vibrate_hangup" value="true" />
<string name="preferred_cdma_network_mode_key">4</string>
<boolean name="button_return_home" value="true" />
<boolean name="button_black_regex" value="false" />
<string name="sip_call_options_key">SIP_ADDRESS_ONLY</string>
<boolean name="button_vibrate_45" value="false" />
<string name="button_voicemail_provider_key"></string>
<string name="button_trackball_answer_timed">-1</string>
<string name="preferred_network_mode_key">4</string>
<boolean name="button_always_proximity" value="false" />
<boolean name="button_left_hand" value="false" />
<boolean name="button_screen_awake" value="false" />
<string name="cdma_system_select_key">2</string>
<boolean name="button_show_organ" value="true" />
<boolean name="button_vibrate_outgoing" value="true" />
<boolean name="button_led_notify" value="true" />
<boolean name="button_vibrate_call_waiting" value="false" />
<boolean name="bg_incall_screen" value="false" />
<string name="button_trackball_hangup_timed">-1</string>
</map>
# cat vm_numbers.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<int name="#FWDSettings#Length" value="0" />
<string name="#VMNumber">**********</string>
</map>
```